# is it possible to set <mat-hint> text color from typescript Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 5 here I am trying to set different hint colors based on condition.

```
<mat-hint style="color:#32CD32">{{hintOTP}}</mat-hint>
```

By using the above line I can set a specific text color for the hint text .

I know another way to achieve my goal is keeping different mat hint and hide and show them based on validation.

I want to know that is there any other way to do it effectively from typescript or ?

Comment: You can use `ngStyle={color: yourColorVariable}`, and set the value of `yourColorVariable` to whatever you want the color to be

Comment: can you give me any code samples @user184994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML use the following:

```
<mat-hint [ngStyle]="{color: hintColor}">HINT</mat-hint>
```

Then, in the TS code, you can change the color like so:

```
this.hintColor = '#ff0000'
```

Which would change the hint to red.

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-xjhx4s?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a class.

i.e:

in your `html` file:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter some input">
    <mat-hint class="some-color">some hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

in your `CSS` file:

```
.some-color {
   color: #4caf50; /* green */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `CSS` file:

```
mat-hint {
   color: #32CD32 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***i am  doing this in my code to change background  color***

```
 <nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="background">
    <mat-icon (click)="toggleBackground()">invert_colors</mat-icon>


    toggleBackground() {
        this.background = this.background ? '' : 'primary';
      }
```